Compare string with day and month of date
Using JavaScript, I need to add a class to a HTML element depending on the current day and month. To do this, I would like to compare the data-date of the elements ("09-20", "09-21", ...) with the day and month of the current date.
Unfortunately my script doesn't work. I'm an absolute beginner in JS, so sorry for my rookie mistakes.


$(function() {
  var a = new Date();
  $(".grid-item").each(function() {
    var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');

    if (a.getMonth() + "-" + a.getDay() == specifiedDate) {
      $(this).addClass('today');
    }
  });
});
.grid-item {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.today {
  background: yellow;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-20"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-21"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-22"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-23"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-24"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-26"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Both getMonth and getDay return an integer. And month are counted starting at zero, so today, September 20th, gets you 8-20. Still surprised that you don't find any of these elements ...?

Looping over all those elements is rather superfluous to begin with - attribute selectors exist! $('[data-date="09-22"]') can select that particular element for you directly - so all you still need to do, is dynamically assemble the 09-22 portion of that, based on the current date, correctly ...

My bad above, getDay does not get you 20, because that method returns the number of the day of the week. You actually want getDate instead.

getDay() returns a day of the week, not the day of the month; I believe you want getDate(). Additionally, your attributes have padded zeroes, while the date functions do not, so the string compare won't work that way (because the data-date attributes are strings).

Your first steps are to use the browser's development console to see what values are actually produced here:
if (a.getMonth() + "-" + a.getDay() == specifiedDate) {

For example:


const a = new Date();
console.log(a.getMonth());
console.log(a.getDay());



Are those values what you expect?  Currently today the values are 8 and 5.  Combined into a string in the format you're using that would be "8-5".  Which simply doesn't match any of the HTML elements you're using.
Your next step is to look at documentation for these functions if the results are unexpected.
For getMonth we learn that the values are 0-based.  So September is 8.  We'd need to either add 1 to the result or subtract 1 from the values in the data.
For getDay we learn that it returns the current day of the week, not the current day of the month.  For that we'd need to use getDate instead.
Putting these things together, we can correct the logic:


$(function() {
   var a = new Date();     
    $(".grid-item").each(function() {
        var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');       

        if ((a.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + a.getDate() == specifiedDate) {
            $(this).addClass('today');
        }
    });
});
.grid-item {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.today {
  background: yellow;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-20"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-21"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-22"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-23"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-24"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-26"></div>



Observe that the leading "0" has been removed from the months in the HTML, we're adding 1 to getMonth(), and we're using getDate().

Though it's of course also worth noting that as another user points out the loop isn't even necessary.  Additional improvements could also involve using template literals instead of concatenating strings.  For example:


$(function() {
   var a = new Date();
   $(`div.grid-item[data-date="${(a.getMonth() + 1)}-${a.getDate()}"]`).addClass('today');
});
.grid-item {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.today {
  background: yellow;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-20"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-21"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-22"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-23"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-24"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="9-26"></div>




That works perfect! Thank you all so much for your phantastic and quick help :-)

I just tried to save the [data]-element and combine the date with the grid-item-class: 
Unfortunately this doesn't work:
$(div.grid-item-${(a.getMonth() + 1)}-${a.getDate()}).addClass('today');
Any idea?

@AndreasBöttcher: That seems to work fine when I test it.  If you can provide a [mcve] which demonstrates your attempt and the problem you've encountered, that could be a starting point for a new question about that specific problem.  Be sure to also include specifics other than "this doesn't work", to include what behavior you are observing vs. what behavior you are expecting, why you're expecting that exact behavior, what debugging you have done, etc.

Sorry, you're right! My careless mistake was, that the css rule is only for "grid-item". grid-item-9-20 can't work of course ;-)

I just can't get it to work.  with $(li.menu-item-${(a.getMonth() + 1)}-${a.getDate()}).addClass('heute'); works fine in fiddle, but not in wordpress-template. I've inserted the function between  within the body. Isn't it correct?

... javascript doesn't add the class to the li-element.

@AndreasBöttcher: When the code is executed on the page, are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Now is the time to do some debugging.  Is the resulting selector what you expect?  Does the selector find any matching elements?  If you run it manually after loading the page, is the behavior different?  Maybe the element(s) being targeted don't exist on the page yet when the code runs?  You're going to have to do some testing and investigating to narrow down the problem.

After changing $(function() to jQuery(function() it now works fine!

a way to do this...
-> doc on .toISOString() method


const dateRef = new Date().toISOString().substring(5,10); // -> `MM-DD` 

document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item').forEach( elm =>
  {
  elm.classList.toggle('today', elm.dataset.date === dateRef);
  });
.grid-item {
  width       : 4em;
  height      : 2em;
  float       : left;
  background  : #eba4c2;
  margin      : .3em;
  text-align  : center;
  line-height : 2em;
  box-sizing  : border-box;
  }
.today {
  background  : yellow;
  border      : red 1px solid;
  }
.grid-item::before {
  content     : attr(data-date);
  }
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-20"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-21"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-22"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-23"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-24"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="09-26"></div>




Pretty clever use of Date.toISOString()
